# Updating view multiple times in 1 controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

New to Rails & Web Development. I have a DOM element that I want to modify. I currently have a separate Javascript file to modify the DOM.

```
function start_loading_bar(msg) {
  loading_message(msg)
  $('#progress').fadeIn()
}
function loading_message(msg) {
  $('.progress-message').text(msg + "...")
}
```

This is linked to a onclick event that a form submit button starts.

```
= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success", onclick: "start_loading_bar('Loading Feed data to Amazon');", remote: true
```

Once this button is clicked, the JS executes, then a controller function that handles the form submission is executed. Within this controller function I want to call the same JS function multiple times. To my understanding, I need the controller to

```
respond_to do |format| 
    format.js { render js: "loading_message(msg);" }
end
```

in order to call the js function, I dont think I can have multiple respond_to blocks in one function.

Maybe I am approaching this problem incorrectly.

To give a bit more context. This JS function is linked to a loading bar, when I execute `$('.progress-message').text(msg + "...")` the loading bars text is set, then `$('#progress').fadeIn()` will remove `display:none;` on `$(#progress)` and fade it in gradually.

My ultimate goal is to have a form submit button start the loading bar with a generic message, then the controller will modify the loading bar message based on what part of the process its in. I have 3 discrete steps in the controller, so, for example, I want the text to be...

'step 1/3'

'step 2/3'

'step 3/3'

at different parts of the controllers function.

Which would require me to call

`loading_message('step 1/3');`

`loading_message('step 2/3');`

`loading_message('step 3/3');`

Im thinking I will have to break up the controller into smaller parts and each will respond_to in JS with the function call.

However, I wanted to ask to see if im overlooking a better/more elegant solution.

Comment: As far as I know you can't run client-side javascript from the server-side... but it looks like there is an eventlistener for checking upload progress via the headers returned.  (I'm assuming the server has to support this...) This site has some examples: http://christopher5106.github.io/web/2015/12/13/HTML5-file-image-upload-and-resizing-javascript-with-progress-bar.html

Comment: Another thing to consider is using callbacks in your javascript functions.  This is how your controller can communicate with the client-side javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question I would ask is what is taking so long that you will require such a high level feedback to your user, perhaps you should send it to a background worker, which means you will probably still need to notify your user in some way.

Unless you open a websocket, or use something like Pusher it's not a simple feat to have your controller update your JS.

Otherwise, your second idea, if the controller actions are completely different processes, then it makes sense for the UI to request each step. This will result in a lot more network calls and a lot more can go wrong. So again, do you really need that level of feedback.

I'm not really sure what you need to do but if it's going to take a long time, push it to a Sidekiq job and then implement a Pubsub like Pusher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The task is uploading data from my app to amazon via their API. Submitting the data to amazon on my end isnt a long task, however, once amazon receives the data, it takes them ~5 minutes before they tell you if the data was uploaded successfully or not. So my app will submit the data, then use a uid for the submission to check its status. im going to explore sidekiq, it might be useful for this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm... In this case I would definitely look at some form of pubsub. Reason being is your frontend would have to keep polling your API, which then polls aws, which is fine for low volumes and to keep costs down. 

You could use aws lambda to listen to that event and then use their pubsub to notify your frontend, as well as your backend once the Job is finished and as aws supports Ruby, it's very possible. I believe there are already GEMS that do this.